# Typescript Error: "A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members." when implementing Partial

Tags: typescript, class

I have this code, which worked just fine until I updated Typescript:

```js
class DefaultRouteConfig implements Partial<RouteConfig> {
  public meta = { layout: LayoutDefault };
}
```

After the update, Typescript complains about it:

```
19:37 A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.
    17 | }
    18 |
  > 19 | class DefaultRouteConfig implements Partial<RouteConfig> {
       |                                     ^
    20 |   public meta = { layout: LayoutDefault };
    21 | }
```

The error messages isn't really clear about what to do in this case (when you are not knee deep into Typescript).

Comment: What does it even mean to class to implement a partial of something? It does literally nothing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am now on TS 3.9.9. I was on an older 3.9.x version before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `implements Partial<RouteConfig>` tells *you*, me, and other humans something about `DefaultRouteConfig`, it doesn't tell the TypeScript compiler anything about it, because what it basically says is that `DefaultRouteConfig` might or might not have any of `RouteConfig`'s properties...and that would be true if the `implements` clause weren't there at all.

One of the most useful things I ever read about TypeScript's type system is that it's [*structural*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), not [*nominal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system). That is, it's based on the shape of types (for instance, what properties objects have and what types those properties have), not the *names* of types (like, say, Java or C#). So for example, this is perfectly valid TypeScript code:

```typescript
// Defined in one place
interface A {
    example: string;
}

// Defined in another place
interface B {
    example: string;
}

// ...

function something(param: A) {
    // ...
}

const x: B = {example: "Hi there"};

something(x);
```

Although we've declared `x` as being of type `B`, it's just fine to pass it in to `something` despite `something`'s parameter being of type `A`. That's because `x` has everything `A` has, so to TypeSript, it's a valid `A` object. The name of the type it was declared with is irrelevant.

That's why that `implements` clause isn't helping TypeScript with anything. Even if `RouteConfig` has property `x` and `DefaltRouteConfig` has property `x`, TypeScript doesn't need `implements Partial<RouteConfig>` to know that the `x` can satisfy part of `RouteConfig`'s type contract. TypeScript already knows that, because it looks at the shape of objects, not the names of those shapes.

I don't know why TypeScript started complaining about that, but to fix the error, just remove the `implements` clause entirely as it had no effect. You could add a comment if you want (though the name of the class is already fairly clear).

Comment: Thanks. I also read up on classes implementing a partial interface. On another place, I got the suggestion "You have to make a mapped type out of everything or intersect in the partial config in the end" which confused me even more, haha. I guess I will just remove the partial implementation as you suggested. BTW, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @Phillipp - Glad that helped! Downvotes always make me question what I've got wrong (that's the point of them -- well, that and signalling to others that something is wrong). In this case I'm just not seeing it, but that could easily be my failure. Ah, well, ... :-) Happy coding!

Comment: I upvoted your answer to retain the balance :D I removed the Partial implementation and added a comment about the reason. Typescript complained no further. Thanks for the help.